# Troubles with loading json file

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Today programming my bot I've needed to do command that will edit json file for guild setting,

But for some reason, I've get an error

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable
```

All I'm doing is this

```
    with open('database.json') as file:
         loadedFile = json.load(file)

    for checkingGuild in loadedFile["guilds"]:
        if int(checkingGuild["guild-id"]) == ctx.guild.id:
            guild = checkingGuild
            break

    guild["global-group-id"] = int(ID)

    with open('database.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(loadedFile,f, indent=4)
```

The json.load(file) is doing the problem but I don't know why! When I'm joining guild this thing works fine but for some reason this is happening!
Please answer if you know how to fix it!

Comment: Can you please add the whole traceback?

Comment: I don't know what is traceback? You mean full error?

Comment: Yeah to see what part of your code actually gives the error.

Comment: Using your example doesnt produce the error your showing

Comment: I said the json.load(file) is giving the error

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example. I have created a json file, loaded it and dumped it without the error you show. are you able to make a minimal code that we can run to replicate your issue

Comment: Do you want me to send whole code? It is discord bot idk where is problem and I cant for  that you cant reproduce that

Comment: I don't think that error can come from `json.load()`, only from `json.dump()`.

Comment: are you setting `loadedFile` to a different value somewhere in your code?